# Regex to detect preferred stock symbols

Tags: regex

To start off, regex is probably the least talented aspect within my programming belt, this is what I have so far:
`\D{1,5}(PR)\D+$`

`\D{1,5}` because common stock symbols are always a maximum of 5 letters
`(PR)` because that is part of the pattern that needs to be searched (more below in the background info)
`\D+$` because I'm trying to match any single letter at the end of the string

*A small tidbit of background*
Preferred stock symbols are not standardized and so every platform, exchange, etc has their own way to display them. Having said that, most display a special character in their name, which makes those guys easy to detect. The characters are
`[] {'.', '/', '-', ' ', '+'};`
The trickier ones all have a similar pattern:
*{symbol}PR{0}*
*{symbol}p{0}*
*{symbol}P{0}*
Where `0` is just any single letter A-Z

Here is a sample data set for the trickier ones:

```
PSAPRZ
PSApA
PSApZ
PSAPA
PSAPZ
```

My regex seems to be working for the first one, since I'm specifically looking for (PR) and matching any single letter character at the end, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to also detect the patterns that end in `p{0}` or `P{0}` in the same regex. I completely gave up trying to incorporate finding the special symbols because I can easily just do a `string.Contains` on the target string for any of those chars. The more important part is figuring out these trickier ones.

**How do I get my regex statement to also detect the p{0} and P{0} matches within the same regex statement?**

*Edit 1*
If you're curious at the madness of different possibilities, including the "easy to detect" versions, grab a popcorn, here you go :)

```
PSA.PA
PSA.PR.A
PSA/PA
PSAPRA
PSA-A
PSA PRA
PSA.PRA
PSA.PA
PSA+A
PSA/PRA
PSApA
PSAPA
PSA-PA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^[A-Z]{1,5}([Pp]|PR)[A-Z]$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start
- `[A-Z]{1,5}` - one to five uppercase letters
- `([Pp]|PR)` - capture group used for: uppercase `P` or lowercase `p` or uppercase `PR`
- `[A-Z]` - one uppercase letters
- `$` - anchor at end

UPDATE after EDIT 1 in question. To support the odd formats with `.`, `/`, `-`, `+` use this:

```
^[A-Z]{1,5}[.\/\s\+\-]?([Pp]|PR\.?)[A-Z]$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start
- `[A-Z]{1,5}` - one to five uppercase letters
- `[.\/\s\+\-]?` - optional single character `.`, `/`,  , `+`, `-`
- `([Pp]|PR\.?)` - capture group used for: uppercase `P`, or lowercase `p`, or uppercase `PR` followed by optional `.`
- `[A-Z]` - one uppercase letters
- `$` - anchor at end

Note on anchors: Use `^...$` anchors if you only have the stock symbol in the string. If you have text with a stock symbol anywhere within, use word boundaries `\b...\b` instead.

Learn more about regex: https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Comment: I ended up adding a `?` after the `([Pp]|PR\.?)` because the final iteration you gave did not capture `PSA-A` or `PSA+A`

Comment: Hmm, actually that last change made it recognize `BTCUSD` as a valid preferred stock, which is wrong, I've pivoted to this now `^[A-Z]{1,5}[.\/\s\+\-]?([Pp]|PR\.?|[-]|[+])[A-Z]$`